# How to control JsonView visibility of foreign/packaged object attributes?

Tags: java, ajax, jackson

My data object includes a mix primitives and data objects from libraries I am using in my project. I know I can control what data gets returned to the browser in Ajax calls by leveraging the @JsonView annotation, but this doesn't work for the data objects defined in libraries - because the fields are not annotated in the data object definition in those libraries. Example below, where LatLng is from a [geospatial library](https://github.com/JavadocMD/simplelatlng/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javadocmd/simplelatlng/LatLng.java) I am using. How do I workaround this? I want latitude and logitude from LatLng to be included in the Ajax response.

```
import com.javadocmd.simplelatlng.LatLng;

public class Waypoint
{
  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private int number;

  private int previousNumber;

  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private LatLng latLon;
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I tried simply wrapping the third party object, which works:

```
public class LatLng extends com.javadocmd.simplelatlng.LatLng implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -5859289528464880247L;

  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private long latitude;

  @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
  private long longitude;

  public LatLng(double latitude, double longitude)
  {
    super(latitude, longitude);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

As [suggested by Jan Chimiak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35382323/2625924), MixIns is the better way to go. No need to update all the object references to a new wrapper class... I added the following to my MVC

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters)
{
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().mixIn(LatLng.class, LatLngMixIn.class).build();
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper));
    super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
}
```

and defined my MixIn as follows:

```
public abstract class LatLngMixIn
{
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private long latitude;

    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private long longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mixins. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations

This way you can define your annotations in *your* class, regardless what was defined in 3rd party lib.